# Android Jwplayer KeyDown Overriding

Tags: android, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

does jwplayer implements its own function for KeyCode /Event to forward/backward/stop the playerview?
i have used this 
`

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            Log.e(TAG, "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN: ");
         return true;
      }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

but this is now working. Is there any other way to override the Key? Thanks in advance